# nfs mounting error, nfs: Unknown parameter 'ip'

Tags: linux, yocto, nfs, u-boot

I was trying to make nfs mounting by following the document of bootlin. I set the parameters as following;

```
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw
nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/nfs,nfsvers=3,
ip=192.168.0.100:::::usb0 g_ether.dev_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:02
g_ether.host_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:01'

setenv bootcmd 'mmc dev 0; devnum=${mmcdev}; setenv devtype mmc;
mmc rescan; run loadimage; run findfdt; run mmcloados'
saveenv
```

it did not work, I get the following ;

```
[    8.007915] nfs: Unknown parameter 'ip'
[   18.407811] nfs: Unknown parameter 'ip'
[   38.887802] nfs: Unknown parameter 'ip'
[   68.967793] nfs: Unknown parameter 'ip'
[   99.047785] nfs: Unknown parameter 'ip'
[   99.051674] VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS.
```

any suggestions where should I look to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reading `ip` as a parameter of `nfsroot`:

```
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw
nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/nfs,nfsvers=3,
                                  ^
                                  |
----------------------------------

ip=192.168.0.100:::::usb0 g_ether.dev_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:02
g_ether.host_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:01'
```

`ip` should be a separate option:

```
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw ip=192.168.0.100:::::usb0 g_ether.dev_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:02
g_ether.host_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:01 nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/nfs,v3'
```